# Is it possible to invoke a helper_method from another Helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two `Helpers`, `ExamsHelper` and `ResultsHelper`

```
exams_helper.rb

module ExamsHelper
  def get_data
    ...
  end
end

results_helper.rb

module ResultsHelper
  def find_result
    ...
  end
end
```

Is it possible to access the `get_data` method in `ResultsHelper`.

I know that if I am declaring it on the `ApplicationHelper`, I can access it. Is there any other solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use `include`:

```
module ResultsHelper
  include ExamsHelper

  def find_result
    get_data # works
  end
end
```